# Access Asset Catalog images in TVML

Tags: tvos, tvml

I there any way to access images in contained within a local Asset Catalog from within TVML on the AppleTV?

I notice several of the templates in [this example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505) call out to `resource://` URLs, which are common use images ([more info on the dev forms](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18604)).  Here's an example button that gets rendered with the cloud symbol:

```xml
<buttonLockup>
  <badge src="resource://button-cloud" class="whiteBadge" />
  <title>Title 3</title>
</buttonLockup>
```

[image: TVML Cloud Button]

I tried pointing to some of my own resources instead of `button-cloud` but didn't have any success.

I have been able to change the icon on these buttons by linking to an externally served image like so:

```xml
<buttonLockup>
  <badge src="http://localhost:5000/static/heartFull.png" class="whiteBadge" width="50" height="50"/>
  <title>Title 3</title>
</buttonLockup>
```

Since these buttons will be re-used throughout my app, I'd rather load them locally than repeatedly calling them over HTTP if possible.

Comment: Here's my same question on the Apple Dev Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/62622

Comment: According to an Apple rep in the thread linked above there (currently) is no way to do this.  I've filed an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com (you could file one too if this would be helpful to you).

Comment: Some resources are documented in [Resource Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ResourceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH44-SW7), however there is no cloud icon there.

Comment: Be careful with this.  I used a full URL for my image (not just localhost) and the image worked on the simulator...but failed to load when run on on the actual device.

Comment: @DarrenEhlers I had no such problem when loading from a HTTPS URL. Make sure you're using HTTPS or [have whitelisted HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31254874/1304462).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had some success linking directly to the filesystem

```
<badge src=\"file:///<url to bundle>/<relative path to resource>/<icon>.png\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" />
```

with... `url to bundle` from `NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.absoluteString`, `relative path` according to your setup, eg. `resources`, `images`, ... and  `icon` well, your image to show on the badge.

Pulling from `Assets.xcassets` hasn't worked out so far, but then I am still in training. :-D

Comment: Thanks @Baa  Unfortunately my TVML is generated server side so `NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL` isn't going to cut it for me.  Still, nice work, I'm upvoting in hopes it helps someone else.

Comment: @nickv2002 - How about having your server include some special token (like `%RESOURCES%`), that you could inflate on Apple TV just before the page is actually brought into view?

Comment: That might work but it still lacks the the ease and utility of just pointing to Asset Catalogs.  I'm just starving a few images up over the web for now hoping this gets addressed in tvOS 10 or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think the icons namespaced with `resource` are provided by the OS itself and can't be modified. This is only a hunch and I haven't verified it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ResourceValues.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Baa, really helped me out! Just wanted to add that in order to reference the path to the bundle on the JS side, I needed to add the following Swift code to my AppDelegate.swift file within the `appController(_ appController: TVApplicationController, evaluateAppJavaScriptIn jsContext: JSContext)` function (may need to be manually added, if you don't see it):

```
jsContext.setObject(Bundle.main.bundleURL.absoluteString, forKeyedSubscript: "BUNDLE_URL" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)
```

Then on the JS side, I could load static images from the bundle with the following:

```
const imageFromBundle = `${BUNDLE_URL}myImageName.png`;
```

Note, as far as I could see, the `file:///` prefix was unnecessary and loading bundled images worked fine for me without it.